# How to get product price from \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item

Tags: magento2, cart, price, quote, quoteitem

I need to get the product price from `\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item`.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
/** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item */ 
$item->getProduct()->getPrice()
```

as `getProduct()` is not a function for $item.
I don't need `$item->getPrice() or $item->getBasePrice()` .

How to get the product price.

I am already in another loop

```
foreach ($totals->getItems() as $item) {
        $item->getItemId() // use this id to get product price from sql query
        $item->setData("base_old_price",$item->getPrice());
        $items[] = $item->__toArray();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need this in some controller or your are on cart phtml?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir i need it in Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php

Comment: Or tell me the sql approach , i can get the item id from $item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need cart helper for this.

add this code

```
protected $cartHelper;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    ...
}
```

After this you can get items and product prices from this code:

Before your loop you can get product prices against items

```
$itemsToPrice = array();
$cartItems = $this->cartHelper->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item){
    $itemsToPrice[$item->getId()] = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

After that in your current loop you can get product price like this:

```
$price = $itemToPrice[$item->getId()];
```

Comment: but i am already in another loop..  foreach ($totals->getItems() as $item) {
            $item->setData("base_old_price",$item->getPrice());
            $items[] = $item->__toArray();
        }, cant i just use a sql query appraoch by extracting item id from $item->getItemID()

Comment: updated question as well

Comment: Updated answer as well :)

Comment: from `$totals->getItems()` you cannot get product price, even you cannot get product id, that's why you need cart helper

Comment: hey buddy it worked, minor mistake, why you deleted your answer, just wanted to upvote and accept it

Comment: That's great. Really good to hear that :)

Comment: I didn't delete my answer. I have updated it.